# WSO2 Api end point giving Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

When I restart the wso2 server, its starting to consume the messages from queue and any other request from browser am getting read time out issue. This behavior is happening once in a while. What could be the reason and how to avoid it? Can some please help me out.